# Hot to convert TXT File to Array of struct - segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, segmentation-fault, coredump

Trying to extract data from a text file and put this data in an array.

File contains a certain amount of lines, each one following the same disposition :

```
Number FamilyName FirstName GPA
```

The array needed is an array of struct.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 25

typedef struct ppl {
    int login;
    char *p_name;
    char *p_surname;
}person;

int main(void)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    person *data=malloc(MAX*sizeof(person)); 
    float *gpa=malloc(MAX*sizeof(float)); 
    size_t length=0;

    FILE* txtfile;

    if ((txtfile=fopen("file.txt","r"))==NULL) return -1;

    int i=0;               // the counter for the for loop
    int buf_ID;            // buffer variable for the sscanf test
    char buf_name[256];    // same
    char buf_surname[256]; // same
    float buf_grade;       // same

    while ((read = getline(&line, &length,txtfile)) != -1 && i<MAX) 
    {
        if(sscanf(line,"%d %s %s%*s %f", &buf_ID, buf_name, buf_surname, &buf_grade)==4)
        {  
             data[i].login=buf_ID;
             data[i].p_name= malloc(strlen(buf_name)+1);
             strcpy(data[i].p_name, buf_name);
             data[i].p_surname= malloc(strlen(buf_surname)+1);
             strcpy(data[i].p_surname, buf_surname);
             gpa[i]=buf_grade;

             i++;
         }
     }                        

    int j;

    printf("ID | Name | Surname | GPA\n");

    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d | %s | %s | %f\n", data[j].login, data[j].p_name, data[j].p_surname, gpa[j]);
    }
    fclose(txtfile);
    return 0;
}
```

(Frequently edited code - I'm filling with useless text because the post doesn't get published otherwise)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Do I need to allocate memory in the declaration of my array, or in the if(sscanf) loop?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Homework indeed, but in my defence we haven't learned about the files and manipulating them in C in my lectures yet. I gathered the info on Google.

Comment: @Iris de[fence](https://contentgrid.homedepot-static.com/hdus/en_US/DTCCOMNEW/fetch/Category_Pages/Lumber_and_Composites/Fencing/chain-link-fence.jpg)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie As you said, I added the  "if ((txtfile=fopen("file.txt","r"))==NULL) return -1;" and allocated memory for my person array: I need MAX times the size of my structure. But I still get the segmentation fault error.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I attempted to debug the code. I received this: A syntax error in expression, near `if(sscanf(line,"%d %s %s%*s %f",&ID,name,surname,&grade)==4)' when I stepped to the if(sscanf==4). And when executing the program normally I got: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
62 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S: No such file or directory.

Comment: Also I got this after I typed where: #0  __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62
#1  0x00007ffff7a649d2 in _IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:35
#2  0x0000555555554ad6 in main () at tp1_exo1.c:54

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I see your answer and your other comments disappeared. I guess you deleted them? Sorry for the delay, and sorry for making you wasting your time.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for the `p_name` and `p_surname` members of your struct before you write to them. Also, it would be good if you showed your complete current code in your question. It's not possible to write an answer if one has to guess about everything.

Comment: @Swordfish I allocated memory for the members. And this is currently my full code. Did I miss something important?

Comment: I'll restore my answer. Let's continue.

Comment: @Iris Your `data` is a pointer to `MAX` thingies of type `person`. Each of these `data[0 ... MAX-1]` `person` thingies has a `p_name` and a `p_surname`. With  `data->p_name = malloc(100);` and `data->p_surname = malloc(100);` you only allocate memory for the `p_name` and `p_surname` of the first of these `MAX` `person`s.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Very good! See my updated answer for the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you now allocated memory for your array. Good.

Now about the `char *` buffers `buf_name` etc. Maybe best to do a static allocation here, for exampl

```
char buf_name[256];
```

You are going to re-use this buffer, so static allocation is fine.

---

Next step:

Lookup the getline function: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html
and check that all parameters are correct.

---

Now take your debugger and step the program to the `sscanf`. Step over it and inspect if the variables have been read correctly by `sscanf` (using a debugger is an important part of learning C).

The next thing is to ask yourself if your array of persons has all the memory it needs. If not, how are you going to allocate that memory?

---

You have allocated an array of persons using malloc. Each person has some data associated with it. The data consist of *primitive types* and *composite types*. A primitive type is an int, float, double and char. A composite type consists of a number of these. A string is a composite type because it consists of more than one char.

So your persons in the array have string data associated with them, as pointers, but the pointers have no memory associated with them. You need to allocate memory to hold the string data. Your data->p_name=malloc(MAX*100);` is not correct.

With each person you read, you should allocate the string memory to hold the string data that `sscanf` put in the fixed size buffers:

```
data[i].p_name= malloc(strlen(buf_name)+1);
strcpy(data[i].p_name, buf_name);
```

and the same for the other string data. (You do this in the loop, of course!)

Nb: for a primitive type the data is allocated by the compiler; for a composite type you must allocate the memory.

Nb: a string in C is terminated with a null character. Therefor the memory needed is one more than the length of the string.

> **What is that second `sscanf` doing there in your loop???**

Finally, copy the ID:

```
data[i].login= buf_id;
```

*Note that you do not store the grade in the person and `gpa` has no memory allocated (so you can get a seg fault again).*

---

Your program will run now without a seg fault. But your loops are incorrect:

You have a for loop that loops exactly 25 times; within the loop you have a while loop that reads data and puts it in persons. But the index of persons is only updated in the for loop, not in the while loop. Once the last data line has been read, the while loop stops and the next iteration of the for loop starts. However, there is not more data.

So you need another type of loop, one that loops *at most* 25 times (as you have no more persons than that) and that stops of there is no more data.

A for loop can be fine; a while loop can be fine too. But not both. Can you come up with these two variants?

---

Your program runs now. As a final point: "clean up!" Remove things no longer needed, make sure the code is properly indented and formatted and add a loop to print the array, so you can check & see it ran correctly.

I hope you had fun developing this program.

Comment: I did it. No segmentation fault anymore with this modification alone. But when I try to printf one of the values of the array (like data (1]) segmentation fault is back.

Comment: Step by step. Lots more problems to fix before it works. Did you read on getline and check its parameters?

Comment: Forgot to edit it in my post but I initialized length to 0.

Comment: @Iris, how is it going? You may skip using the debugger for now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I got this with the debugger: #0 __strlen_avx2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strlen-avx2.S:62 #1 0x00007ffff7a649d2 in _IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:35 #2 0x0000555555554ad6 in main () at tp1_exo1.c:54

Comment: Forget the debugging for now. But study debugging when you have time. We'll fix your program without a debugger (I am a mental debugger :-))

Comment: So does my new loop (for or while) have to be within my current while loop? Or does this new loop replace the for and the while? Also the 1st sscanf is a test to check the arguments, and the 2nd sscanf transfers the arguments in the array.

Comment: The new loop replaces  both your for and while loop. With the malloc and strcpys you HAVE put your data in the array. (Oh dear...)

Comment: You only need to to copy the ID and grade to the peson in the array, `data[i].login= buf_id;` etc.

Comment: What about the login (the int number)? Is it put in the array with sscanf? (I guess I should delete the ifsscanf test?...)

Comment: Another thing: the read>16 is to eliminate unrelevant or empty lines

Comment: You must assume the data in the file is correct. Advanced handling of incorrect files is outside your scope now.

Comment: I did the while variant of loop.

Comment: Excellent! The loop stops when no data has been read, and loops no more than 25 times. Last thing: `gpa` has no memory allocated, which can still cause a seg fault.

Comment: There is no better commitment of time than helping the new programmers coming along learn to program correctly. Good job prof.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed. Thank you so much PaulOgilvie for helping me. (I allocated memory to *gpa)

Comment: Thank you Iris. Now click on the big 1 at the left of my answer, at the top. It signals you accept my answer as a good help.

Comment: I did the cleanup and clicked the 1 (I thought I upvoted your answer before, I guess it didn't load).

Comment: (Hm, when I clicked on the 1 it said my vote wouldn't be counted because of my reputation points...Too bad)

Comment: The for loop which prints the array prints "0|null|null|0".  BUt that's another story. Anyways, thank you so so much for helping me, you made me spare a great amount of time!

Comment: In the printing loop you use `i` in the print statement as index, but the loop uses `j`: `for (j=0; j<i; j++) printf("...",data[j].login` (note that `j` loops to `i` because you don't know if 25 persons were read).

Comment: Iris, _please_ be very careful and very precise. Many of your errors come from trying to go too fast.

Comment: I corrected the mistake you pointed out, and deleted the %*s in the sscanf, and it works!!! I'm repeating myself, but thank you very very muvh for your help. And you're right, I have a bad habit of doing many things too quickly. I guess tonight has been a very instructive lesson. Thank you for teaching me so much tonight.

Comment: I have formatted your code as it should be, removed all unnecesary stuff and fixed one minor item (`sscanf()==4` - lookup `sscanf`). See how easy it reads now? That also helps in spotting erors.

Comment: Yes I see, everything looks clearer! Thank you again.